# Having a view spitting out a form - the UI way

Tags: views, forms

Suppose I have a lot of entities that match users to some nodes and the entities have a field called "rating" which is/could be a Drupal list of four possible values ranging from interesting to uninteresting.

I want to have a view that spits out all entities related to the currently logged in user and let him choose his rating for each of them. When he comes back later, he should see his choices and be able to edit it.
How to do that?

I know, that it's somehow possible by writing a module. Ideally, I don't want to do that but rather solve it completely with UI.

(I'm not fixed to the entity approach I described above. If you think it's a bad idea, I'll be happy to hear alternate suggestions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [editablefields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module.

I personally find it better to write a custom views handler implementing the Views Form API, but you can try to see how far this takes you.